# How can I set runtime status check on a PR in GitHub?

Tags: github, github-actions

I am setting branch restriction on a repo in GitHub and I am using GitHub Actions as the CI/CD pipeline. There are many workflows defined for this repo and each one will be triggered based on the change path like below code:

```
on:
    pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
    branches:
      - develop
    paths:
      - apps/packages/package-a
```

there are many packages under `apps/packages` directory and each package has its own workflow file.

I am going to set a status check on a PR as below setting:

[image]

the problem is that the above setting is static. Different change in a PR will trigger different workflow. And one PR could trigger more than one workflows if it includes more than one package change. How can I set the status check on the repo setting for dynamic workflow?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there is no way to let multiple workflows "share" a single check. You will somehow have to cramp all package checks into a single workflow, with a check that gathers all package check results. You will have to use an action to detect path changes yourself. A good one is [dorny/paths-filter](https://github.com/dorny/paths-filter)

Example:

```
# check-all-packages.yml
name: Check All Packages
on: 
  pull_request:
    types:
      - opened
      - synchronize
    branches:
      - develop
    paths:
      - apps/packages/**

jobs:
  detect-changed-packages:
    name: Change Detection
    outputs:
      package-a: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.package-a }}
      package-b: ${{ steps.filter.outputs.package-b }}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: dorny/paths-filter@v2
        id: filter
        with:
          filters: |
            package-a:
              - 'apps/packages/package-a'
            package-b:
              - 'apps/packages/package-b'
  
  check-package-a:
    needs: [detect-changed-packages]
    if: ${{( needs.detect-changed-packages.outputs.package-a == 'true' )}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: ./.github/workflows/check-package-a.yml

  check-package-b:
    needs: [detect-changed-packages]
    if: ${{( needs.detect-changed-packages.outputs.package-b == 'true' )}}
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: ./.github/workflows/check-package-b.yml

  final-check:
    name: Final Check
    needs: [check-package-a, check-package-b]
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Report results
        run: |
          if [${{ needs.check-package-a.result }} != "success"]; then
            echo "Package A Failed Check"
            exit 1
          fi

          if [${{ needs.check-package-b.result }} != "success"]; then
            echo "Package B Failed Check"
            exit 1
          fi

          echo "All Packages Passed Check"
```

```
# check-package-a.yml
name: Check Package A
on: 
  workflow_call

jobs:
  # You checks for package A
```

Then in the status check setting, type "Final Check" to search for the `final-check` job and require it to pass for your PR to be merged.

I haven't tested the code but hope it gives you the idea